# C pass string to query and also check if result is empty

Tags: mysql, c

I need to pass a string to inside the query when connecting to a database using C, but since I have not been using C for a long time I don't know the correct way to do it. I tried the below but that doesn't work.

```
if (mysql_query(conn, "select * from t1 where c1 = %s and c2 = %s", sptr->name, sptr->desc)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
}
```

also what is the easiest method to check whether the query returned an empty result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you cannot use format specifiers and corresponding arguments directly inside `mysql_query()` function.

What you need to do is

1. Allocate one temporary buffer.
2. use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to print the query command in the buffer
3. call `mysql_query()` with the buffer as second argument.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? Also what is the simplest method to check whether the query returned an empty result set (in PHP I could do something as simple as `if empty( $result ) {}`.

Comment: @Jack do you want example of `snprintf()`? That I can give, but I have not used `mysql_query()` myself so not sure how it gives back the result (other that the `return` value). Is is stored in `conn`?

Comment: `sprintf(str, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = %s", sptr->name);` and then `mysql_query(conn, sptr);`?

Comment: @Jack `mysql_query(conn, str);` you meant, right? Yes, that's the way.

Comment: Thanks but now I noticed you said `snprintf` not `sprintf`, which should I use, and why?

Comment: @Jack Nice question. see the `snprintf()` limits the total number of bytes written to `n`, thereby limiting the possibility of buffer overflow, just in case your argument is longer than the buffer can hold. It is safer to use `snprintf()` that `sprintf()` because `sprintf()` may try to write past the allocated buffer. Am I understood?